# CakePHP Not understanding the request object

Tags: php, controller, cakephp-2.0

I want to code something that I thought would be fairly straightforward: **accept user input on a field, then update an array of records with that value.** I think I'm stumbling due to my minimal understanding of the Request object. I have a form in my index view

```
<div class="<?php echo $this->request->params['action']; ?>">

<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Invoice', array('action' => 'edit'));
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->input('purchaseOrderNumber');
echo $this->Form->submit('Update Invoices', array('div' => false, 'name' => 'submit'));
?> 

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Invoice Number</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Invoice Date</th>
    </tr>

    <!-- Here is where we loop through our $invoices array, printing out invoice info -->

    <?php foreach ($invoices as $invoice): ?>
        <tr>        
            <td>
                <?php echo $this->Html->link($invoice['Invoice']['invoiceNumber'], array('action' => 'edit', $invoice['Invoice']['id'])); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $invoice['Invoice']['customerName']; ?>
            </td>        
            <td>
                <?php echo $invoice['Invoice']['invoiceDate']; ?>
            </td>          
        </tr>
        <?php
    endforeach;
    echo $this->Form->end();
    ?>

</table>
</div>
```

Simple enough. I want to take the value from the *purchaseOrderNumber* and use it to update the records which were returned in the dataset in the succeeding foreach(). Despite my best 'net search effort for a clue, I haven't found out how I do this. My guess is that it's so obvious to more experienced developers that they found no need to write about it.

Any help would be appreciated. If you need more explanation, just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you don't understand about the Request object, but this is what you could do.

After submitting the Invoice form the form data becomes available to your `edit` method. You can use`$this->data` (which is read-only) or `$this->request->data` (which may be altered) in your *InvoicesController* to do an update query.

The data returned by your form in `$this->data` has the following structure:

```
array(
    'submit' => 'Update Invoices',
    'Invoice' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'purchaseOrderNumber' => '3'
    )
)
```

You don't need the submit value, obviously, but you can use the other data to retrieve the correct invoice with the `id` of **1** and update it with a `purchaseOrderNumber` of **3**.

A theoretical update would be constructed like this:

```
$this->Invoice->save($this->data['Invoice']);
```

Which is similar to this, more verbatim, equivalent:

```
$update = array(
  'Invoice' => array(
    'id' => 1,
    'purchaseOrderNumber' => 3
  )
);

$this->Invoice->save($update);
```

By supplying the `id` alongside other data, Cake "knows" to use UPDATE instead of performing a regular INSERT.

The code above is from memory and may contain errors, but it should point you in the right direction, hopefully.

Comment: I will certainly try it out and update this thread. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I finally found the correct way to access the value.         $invoices = $this->Invoice->find('all');             
        $this->set(compact('invoices'));           
        pr($invoices[0]['Invoice']['purchaseOrderNumber']);  Now just need to add the update

Comment: Ah, but that performs a database query on the table (invoices) for the Invoice model. I was assuming you needed the form data.

Comment: yea, not sure what i want. being self-taught, i encounter situations i cannot adequately explain because i don't know the terminology. i've since found an easier way. for instance, the id will actually be an array of records which needs updating with the new PO number.